# MatLab Rose color by bin size

Tags: matlab, colors, bin, bins

my Problem is the following.
I want to do a rose plot with Matlab. (http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rose.html)
I have the following code:

```
f2=figure('visible','off');
h=rose(degtorad(angles(:,i)),40);
title(['Marker '], 'FontSize',20)
x=get(h,'Xdata');
y=get(h,'Ydata');
g=patch(x,y,[0.3 0.3 0.3]);
saveas(f2,'\roses\marker.jpg')
```

And that is working fine. 
But I now want to change the color of its bins by the size of the bins.
So that the longest bin is black and the shortest is more or less white.
And all the others are more or less dark grey, depending by the size of it.

I hope my question is clear.

Is that possible?
Thanks a lot.
Bant

EDIT:
I traked down the problem I think!
The link beow i a link to a txt-file in my dropbox folder:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u17n4rv0oma5lbk/Angles.txt?dl=0

In this txt-File a bunch of angles is saved.
If I use these angles [they are in degree so I did `*2*pi/360`] instead of `rand([200 1])*2*pi;` it kind of patches the bins wrong. 
the error must be in my angles but I don't know where!
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your data is between 0-2*pi this is easy to do. If it is not, well, put it between that range, it should be not difficult to do.

```
theta = rand([200 1])*2*pi; % create angles between 0-2pi
nbins=12;                    % Define Number of bins

h=rose(theta,nbins);
title(['Marker '], 'FontSize',20) %plot


x=get(h,'Xdata');
y=get(h,'Ydata');

sortedt=sort(theta); % Sort angles
nel=hist(sortedt,nbins); % get amount of angles in each bin

for ii=1:nbins
   sc=(nel(ii)-min(nel))/(max(nel)-min(nel)); % scale between 0-1
   patch(x(1+(ii-1)*4:4+(ii-1)*4),y(1+(ii-1)*4:4+(ii-1)*4),[1 1 1]*sc );

end
```

[image]

EDIT: I just realised that you want the big ones in black. Well just add `sc=1-sc`. Changing this code to work for any colormap should be easy

Comment: Hello, many thanks! That works perfectly fine for one rose! How can I make it work within a loop? When I use it in a loop it works for the first one but not for the rest!? For them either it is coloring all bins in the same color or not the biggest black and the smallest white! Is there some trick with the patch command? (I hope I could make that problem clear)

Comment: @Bant Hi. I dont understand your problem. If you make several roses, just get an `h=rose..` every time you make a new one. I mean it should work. I cant help you more without seing the code. You coudl either: accept the answer and open anew one with your new question or edit this one and put the code where it does not work.

Comment: Hi! well yes sorry about that! I know that question was not very clear! Can you enplane me why you are using a 4 in: patch(x(1+(ii-1)*4:4+(ii-1)*4),y(1+(ii-1)*4:4+(ii-1)*4),[1 1 1]*sc ); That kind of doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: I edited the question! ;) The mistake did not come from using a loop, but is some where in my used angles!

Comment: @Bant The 4 is ther because it seems that `x` stores 4 valus for each bin. just empirically found